# Specify values of a parameter type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have these interfaces:

```
interface IComponent {
  type: string;
  text: string;
}

interface IComponents {
  cc: IComponent;
  lajota: IComponent;
}

interface IMain {
  components: IComponents
}
```

And it is working fine! But now I need to add a new `component` called "caneta".
SO I'll access this with `.components.caneta`. But this new component will have a single attribute:

```
interface IComponentCaneta {
  property: string;
}  

// Add the new component to be used on IMain
interface IComponents {
  cc?: IComponent;
  lajota?: IComponent;
  caneta?: IComponentCaneta;
}
```

The problem is I have a method that do some work depending on the attribute `type` like:

```
//for each component I have in components objects 
function myFunc(component: IComponent) {
_.each(components (val, key) => {
  if (key === 'cc') {...}
  else if (value?.type === 'xxx') {  <---- HERE flags error
    components[key].type = 'xxxx'
  }
})
}
```

When I add the new component `caneta`, **Typescript** complains saying:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IComponentCaneta'.

Tried to make `type` optional, but didn't work.

What would be the right thing to do in this situation?
Is there a way to explicitly say that "The attribute of type IComponent will be 'X' 'Y' or 'Z'. Something like

```
function myFunc(component: IComponent ['cc' or 'lajota'])
```

Things I tried and failed:

```
// make type optional
interface IComponent {
  type?: string;
  text: string;
}


// try to infer the object (cc, loja, caneta)
switch (type) {
  case 'cc':
    // ...
    break;
  case 'lajota':
    // ...
    break;
  default: //'caneta'
    // ...
    break;
}

//using IF/ELSE 
if (type === 'cc') {.../}
else if(type === 'lajota') {...}
else if(type === 'caneta') {...}
```

Comment: Can't you just make the "caneta" inside "IComponents" optional? With question mark: caneta?:

Comment: Hey @digitalniweb it already is. Just forgot to write here, sorry. I'll correct that.

Comment: a bit of type confusion here - you declare an interface that allows two different types, yet your code acts as if a it only contains a single type (`IComponent`). Your test must accommodate _all_ types declared in the interface. Test for the keys other than just `cc`

Comment: Hi, @RandyCasburn I just corrected a thing and commented where the error happens. Whenever I try to check the attribute like `value?.type` it flags the error.

Comment: That error occurs because `cc` is not the key for and IComponentCaneta. So if the key is `caneta`, testing for a property that does not exist on IComponentCaneta will throw that error. Your code needs to include an `if else` for when the `key == caneta`

Comment: Please [edit] your code so that it's a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Right now that code spews many errors unrelated to your question.  Also, unless your problem depends on lodash I'd suggest removing it from your example code.  If you do this and want me to take another look, please leave a comment mentioning @jcalz so I'm notified.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [Object Entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
I don't know if there is a "down side" yet. I just wanted a way to iterate through the *components* and make typescript happy.
The only solution I could think of was try to **infer** the object so TS could "see" the right attributes.

```
function myFunc (components: IComponents) {
    Object.entries(components).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
        if (key === 'caneta') {
            components[key].property = 'Hello World';
        } else if(value?.type === 'text') {  <--- No longer gives me errors
            components[key].type = 'NEW TYPE'
        }
    });
}
```

One thing that kind worries me is that when I was trying this code on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) it gave me the following error/warning:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.

on the following lines:

```
components[key].property = 'Hello World';

and
components[key].type = 'NEW TYPE'
```

No errors on my vscode/lint though